# How to deal with situations where loading is interrupted in react-redux applications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following example to illustrate how I update the redux state while loading data from the database in a react-redux application. `learningActionDataOperationBegin` sets `loading` (in the reducer) to `true`, then once the data is fetched from the database, `fetchLearningActionsSuccess` sets `loading` back to `false`. Inside the component, where the database records are displayed, `FetchLearningActions` is called only when initially `loading` is false. I believe this is the common practice with react-redux applications.

However, for example if the browser is closed or if the internet gets disconnected while the data is being loaded, the `loading` stays as `true`, which is a problem since in the next visit to the page `FetchLearningActions` will not get called (because `loading` is still true) and the page will always display `Loading..` text on the screen. I wonder how I should handle this. Any ideas or suggestions?

```
export function FetchLearningActions(submissionId) {

    var url = 'api/LearningAction/FetchLearningActions';

    return dispatch => {

        dispatch(learningActionDataOperationBegin());

        axios.get(url, { params: { submissionId } })
            .then(response => {
                console.log('Learning actions are loaded.');

                const learningActions = new schema.Entity('learningActions');

                const normalizedData = normalize(response.data, [learningActions]);
                dispatch(fetchLearningActionsSuccess(normalizedData.entities.learningActions))
            })
            .catch(error => { learningActionDataOperationFailure(error) });
    }
}
```

Comment: Normally redux does not save it's state so when you leave the page and come back the state would be empty. Are you having these problems because you are persisting redux state?

Comment: @HMR thanks for the comment! yes I am persisting the state...

Comment: Maybe dispatch an action to reset all loading values onbeforeunload

Comment: @hmr where does the code should go? I am using react hooks.

Comment: You could try an effect in the root component, you can use [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#usedispatch) from react-redux to dispatch the action that will reset any data loading values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `learningActionDataOperationFailure(error)` with dispatch.  That action should set `isLoading` to false and maybe set an error flag.  You now can differentiate between states where your app is making a request and whether it finished successfully or not.